# selecting item in div class in Selenium

Tags: selenium

My Html source is pasted below. I would like to select 'TCP IETF' from the list box. How can i do that.

```
<div class="mat-select-content ng-trigger ng-trigger-fadeInContent" style="opacity: 1;"> 
  <mat-option _ngcontent-c14="" class="mat-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" tabindex="0" 
    id="mat-option-0" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="mat-option-text">TCP - without Syslog</span>
    <div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
  </mat-option>

  <mat-option _ngcontent-c14="" class="mat-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" tabindex="0" 
    id="mat-option-1" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="mat-option-text">UDP - without Syslog</span>
    <div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
  </mat-option>

  <mat-option _ngcontent-c14="" class="mat-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" tabindex="0" 
    id="mat-option-2" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="mat-option-text">TCP BSD Syslog</span>
    <div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
  </mat-option>

  <mat-option _ngcontent-c14="" class="mat-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" tabindex="0" 
    id="mat-option-3" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="mat-option-text">UDP BSD Syslog</span>
    <div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
  </mat-option>

  <mat-option _ngcontent-c14="" class="mat-option ng-star-inserted mat-selected mat-active" role="option" tabindex="0" 
    id="mat-option-4" aria-selected="true" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="mat-option-text firepath-matching-node">TCP IETF Syslog</span>
    <div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
  </mat-option>

  <mat-option _ngcontent-c14="" class="mat-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" tabindex="0" 
    id="mat-option-5" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="mat-option-text">UDP IETF Syslog</span>
    <div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
  </mat-option>

  <mat-option _ngcontent-c14="" class="mat-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" tabindex="0" 
    id="mat-option-6" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="mat-option-text">TLS IETF Syslog</span>
    <div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
  </mat-option>

  <mat-option _ngcontent-c14="" class="mat-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" tabindex="0" 
    id="mat-option-7" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="mat-option-text">TLS BSD Syslog</span>
    <div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
  </mat-option>

</div>
```

Comment: Please show  well-format HTML code next time and tag which programming language you prefer.

Comment: Your code trials and the error stack trace (if any)?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear which language you are using to run Selenium, but I will provide an example in C# to give you a starting basis.

An important part of working with listboxes/drop down menus is converting your basic element into a select element, then choosing the element within the list that you actually want to select. In this case, we could select by index. Since we know the element you want is the 5th element in the list, we would use the index of 4.

```
    IWebElement listBox = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("mat-select-content ng-trigger ng-trigger-fadeInContent"));

    var listBoxSelect = new SelectElement(listBox);

    listBoxSelect.SelectByIndex(4);
```